# Как сделать очередь в боте(pytelegrambotapi)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Вообщем есть бот, который создает файлы с помощью pyinstaller и отправляет их человеку.
Проблема в том что pyinstaller не может работать на 100 человек и мне надо организовать очередь в боте.

Answer (score 1):

[queue - Класс синхронизированной очереди](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html)

Пример того, как ждать выполнения поставленных в очередь задач:

```
import threading, queue

q = queue.Queue()

def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        print(f'Working on {item}')
        print(f'Finished {item}')
        q.task_done()

# turn-on the worker thread
threading.Thread(target=worker, daemon=True).start()

# send thirty task requests to the worker
for item in range(30):
    q.put(item)
print('All task requests sent\n', end='')

# block until all tasks are done
q.join()
print('All work completed')
```

Comment: item = q.get() не могли бы подсказать, что означает эта строчка?

Comment: Queue.get([ block [ , timeout]]) - при получении значения можно блокировать очередь, чтобы другой поток не забрал данные. данная функция ждет пока не появятся данные, по истечению тайм-аута, если он задан, срабатывает exception
Queue.get_nowait() - взять значение без ожидания, если данных нет то срабатывает exception

Comment: Она обязательна в написании?

Comment: Можете помочь? в tg:@fleeen